# Connecting to Xero OAuth2 from localhost give CORS Erros

Tags: oauth-2.0, angular7, xero-api, angular-oauth2-oidc

Im connecting to the Xero oauth server 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize' through an Angular 7 app using the `angular-oauth2-oidc` package.

In my authConfig i have the following properties

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize',
  redirectUri: 'http://127.0.0.1:2114/xerocallback',
  clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXX647C2ABBAXXXXXXXXXX',
  scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
  responseType: 'code',
};
```

However, as soon as i initialize the oauth service

```
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
```

i get the following CORS error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'http://localhost:2114' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

any idea of what im doing incorrectly,
any suggestions would be welcomed

Answer (score 8):

The Xero Identity provider doesn't currently support the [PKCE](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/) flow from SPAs and Mobile devices – it only supports `code` flow from server-side web applications (where you provide the `client_secret`). This means you can't currently access our API directly from a browser-based application.

If this would be useful to you, raise a feature request on our UserVoice page and we can look into it: https://xero.uservoice.com/

– Josh (Xero)