# XERO API Develop show me the cross-origin when Request TenantId visa ajax request

Tags: ajax, xero-api

Since I develop the api of the xero, when I get then token is right[https://identity.xero.com/connect/token], but then i request tenantId[https://api.xero.com/connections] show me the error "cross-origin", but it can run in postman.
I do not want to use only sdk e.g Nodejs, C#, but ajax

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the same answer as in this question:
[Connecting to Xero OAuth2 from localhost give CORS Erros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57579835/1941338)

"The Xero Identity provider doesn't currently support the PKCE flow from SPAs and Mobile devices – it only supports `code` flow from server-side web applications (where you provide the `client_secret`). This means you can't currently access the xero API directly from a browser-based application."

Note that the server which accepts your connection is identity.xero.com, for which you're probably using Basic authorisation containing a client id & secret, whereas the server that doesn't accept your connection, api.xero.com, requires Bearer authorisation containing just the access key.